# The cost of MySQL filesort and what's the solution?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm new to optimizing MySQL (cheers for having a high traffic site!) and I'm a little confused by filesort.  I stumbled onto this article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/ with some quick google searching but I can't seem to find any solutions.  Does it mean my queries are merely poorly written, do they lack proper indexes (I've spent some time indexing properly, at least what I think is proper) or is there something else at play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > The truth is, filesort is badly named. Anytime a sort can’t be performed from an index, it’s a filesort. (via mysqlperformanceblog)

So, most likely, you've got a query which isn't making use of a table index. See [MySQL Create Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Bonus!: If you're new to tuning your mysql server for high performance take a look at this:

```
wget mysqltuner.pl # quite the clever domain name ;)
chmod +x mysqltuner.pl
./mysqltuner.pl
```

This script will identify a lot of common mistakes, and make performance suggestions.